# How to conditionally apply source set excludes to build based on parameter provided

Tags: java, gradle

I'm using Gradle 4.4 (edit: issue still present in Gradle 4.8). For reasons my project has the following layout

```
src/main/java/com/company/common
src/main/java/com/company/mod1
src/main/java/com/company/mod2
```

The build can generate either mod1 or mod2, depending on the build task executed. Classes from mod1 shall never use classes from mod2 and vice versa. Therefore I want the build to fail, if either uses classes from the other. However I still want to be able to develop both sources in Eclipse, which is why I only want the build to fail on our CI server. The CI server provides a parameter CI_BUILD. The build file uses the following mechanism to allow this:

**Excludes aren't applied properly here:**

```
ext {
    ext_template_mod1 = [:]
    ext_template_mod1.src_excludes       = "**/mod2/**"

    ext_template_mod2 = [:]
    ext_template_mod2.src_excludes       = "**/mod1/**"

    if (project.hasProperty("mod2")) {
      ext_template = ext_template_mod2
    } else {
      ext_template = ext_template_mod1
    }
}
sourceSets {
  main {
    java {
      if (project.hasProperty("CI_BUILD")) {
        exclude "${project.ext_template.src_excludes}"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

For some reason this doesn't work. `gradlew build -PCI_BUILD` doesn't fail if a source file on mod1 references a source file from mod2.

I fail to understand why it doesn't. If I don't check for the project property, the exclude works as expected:

**Working configuration:**

```
ext {
    ext_template_mod1 = [:]
    ext_template_mod1.src_excludes       = "**/mod2/**"

    ext_template_mod2 = [:]
    ext_template_mod2.src_excludes       = "**/mod1/**"

    if (project.hasProperty("mod2")) {
      ext_template = ext_template_mod2
    } else {
      ext_template = ext_template_mod1
    }
}
sourceSets {
  main {
    java {
      exclude "${project.ext_template.src_excludes}"
    }
  }
}
```

Now `gradlew build -PCI_BUILD` fails as expected when a source file on mod1 references a source file from mod2.

But now my IDE won't recognize the sources in the mod2 folder as sources anymore.

How can I apply excludes to my source set based on the existence of a build parameter?

Answer (score 0):

I've been creating a minimal example and it works just fine there:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

ext {
    ext_template_mod1 = [:]
    ext_template_mod1.src_excludes       = "**/mod2/**"

    ext_template_mod2 = [:]
    ext_template_mod2.src_excludes       = "**/mod1/**"

    if (project.hasProperty("mod2")) {
      ext_template = ext_template_mod2
    } else {
      ext_template = ext_template_mod1
    }
}
sourceSets {
  main {
    java {
      if (project.hasProperty("CI_BUILD")) {
        exclude "${project.ext_template.src_excludes}"
      }
    }
  }
}

jar {
  if (project.hasProperty("CI_BUILD")) {
    exclude "${project.ext_template.src_excludes}"
  }
}
```

The issue above was an artifact of my own build. I had used dynamic task generation and forgotten to provide the parameter I was checking for as a `startParameter.projectProperties`.